# How does NFC unlock work?

Tags: nfc

I am not asking for instructions on how to set it up. I can't find any page or diagram detailing Android's scheme for using NFC modules to unlock devices. What algorithms are used? How about the steps in the scheme? How is the NFC module used if encryption is enabled? Are digital signatures used? Do the tags get programmed when they are set up with a device?

Comment: [This](http://blog.clove.co.uk/2012/06/20/near-field-communication-nfc-explained-the-complete-guide/) may help

Comment: @beeshyams That link doesn't offer any explanations of how Android uses NFC as a method of unlocking.